# React Native Android Build Failure - A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-image-loader'.java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo, react-native-unimodules

I have a React Native Ejected app that builds fine for iOS but fails during the build process on the module expo-image-loader. I am doing a yarn android command and it fails with the following output:

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-image-loader'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)
> KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'debugAndroidTest' not found.

Haven't worked with Gradle before so I am a disadvantage with even how to begin troubleshooting this. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading expo-image-loader manually to 2.1.0 (yarn upgrade expo-image-loader@2.1.0) resolved the issue for me.